# Reference request where Buddha calls a monk "janitor"

Tags: reference-request

Iirc there is a text where the Buddha called a monk "janitor" for being devoted to cleaning.

It's probably in the Dhp commentary but i am not sure.

Two monks ordained, one spent his time practicing whereas the other was cleaning a lot & criticizing the meditator.